# Как избавиться от неправильных вычислений?

Tags: python

```
P = int(input())/100
X = str(input() + ".")
Y = str(input())
summa = float(X + Y)
summa = summa + summa * P
print(summa//1, summa%1 * 100)
```

при выводе может выдавать непонятную дробную часть(67.99999999999997)
как от этого избавиться

Comment: Непонятную для кого? это проявляется в своей лучшей красе точность типа Float =) вам от чего избавится надо? выводить с заданой точностью или иное что то?

Comment: А нельзя ли подробнее, какова задача? И не совсем понимаю смысл в коде summa%1 * 100 -  остаток от деления на 1 целых чисел даст всегда 0, а дробных - вот эти вот самые .99999999999